# How to open URL in new window/tab without leaving the current one?

Tags: html, url, web, browser, frontend

The following `<a>` element would open `www.example.com` in a different tab/window than the current one:

```
<a href="//www.example.com" target="TabOne">Link</a>
```

However, users would be brought to the newly opened tab/window. How can I open URL in new window/tab *without leaving the current one*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [automatic open pop-up new window using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293014/automatic-open-pop-up-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: Know that Firefox has an option setting "When you open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately", so with this option set, staying at the same window may still be limited.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<a href="//www.example.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: Sadly I hate MAC and not sure why Safari cannot use 'standard html'.  The above will work in IE, Edge, Chome, and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Open in current tab:

```
<a href="www.example.com" target="_self">title</a>
```

Open in another tab:

```
<a href="www.example.com" targer="_blank">title</a>
```

Hope this help =))